# absolute measure unit of length

Tags: measure-theory

The measure unit of angles can be defined geometrically using compass and ruler, but the unit of length can not be defined absolutely so today we have different unit length used (feet, meter miles). Historically different unit length are used. I am interested there are attempts by mathematicians who will define unit of length with mathematical tools by using the achievements of physics or such an attempt would be absurd or meaningless.

Comment: You might find the following interesting: http://www.surveyhistory.org/the_standard_meter1.htm

Comment: In Euclidean geometry, there is no natural unit of length.  Dilation by a constant factor preserves all Euclidean relationships.  In Euclid's *Elements*, whenever they want to do a product of lengths and get a length, they must also be given a line-segment called the "unit" length.  NOTE: in non-Euclidean geometry, there IS a natural unit of length.

Comment: See the Wikipedia article on Planck length: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plank_length

Comment: I am not sure that this question qualifies as "measure theory", maybe in a *very very very* abstract sense there is some relation - alas not in a way that I would tag it as measure theory.

Comment: This question is absurd. Mathematicians don't use the achievements of the pshysics. The relation between those two sciences is always the opposite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Units are by definition relative. There is no absolute, *a priori* length. In physics, the closest things might be [Planck length](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plank_length) (and [Planck units](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_units)) the radius of the universe; the Bohr radius of an atom, maybe a Schwarzschild radius?; and the wavelengths of light. But you can't derive them ALL from first principles. There is as of yet no universally defined axiom for any unit of measurement.

Units are interdependent. One needs a system of units. These have cultural origins, but the [SI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units) (Système International -- french nomenclature: noun + adjective) system is widely used in science. There are also elementary units. For example, velocity is distance over time, or energy is mass times velocity squared (mass, distance and time are elementary/fundamental quantities). SI addresses this issue from an operational perspective, defining base units and derived units. Then, there is [dimensional analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis).

If we take the speed of light in a vacuum as a universal constant (an axiom in special relativity theory), then length units can be derived from time units (or vice versa).

In math, we often use radians for angles, which are related to using the "natural" base $e$ for logarithms, which comes from the area under the curve $y=\frac1x$. There are also solid angles in three dimensions, which are defined as a ratio of volumes. So, some units are *a priori* or natural. But we also call these *unitless* numbers (another of which is the [fine structure constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-structure_constant)).